# Nifi processor runs recursively

Tags: apache-nifi

I am exploring nifi, as of I have created processor group with number of processor which basically select data from Oracle DB and insert in to mongoDB. the the flow works as expected.

The flow is  `QueryDatabaseTable -> SplitAvro -> ConvertAvorToJson -> PutMongoRecord`

In `QueryDatabaseTable` I have custom query `select * from employee`, which gives me 100 records and these 100 records inserted into mongoDB. But here issue is `QueryDatabaseTable` is called again and again, so in result same 100 records are get added in mongoDB again and again. Is there any way to stop this repeated execution? Thanks in advance.

Update: I am using `Nifi 1.9.2`

PFB `QueryDatabaseTable`  **setting** tab below

[image]
**Scheduling**

[image]

**Properties**

[image]
[image]

Update 2: Configuration

Comment: please show the parameters you set for  QueryDatabaseTable.

Comment: Set the timer not to be zero where it is default value or change the scheduling with cron.

Comment: @daggett  I have attached the configuration for QueryDatabaseTable

Comment: @Lamanus Yes I have changed `Run Schedule` to non-zore value  and its works

Answer (score 0):

Use maximum-value columns if you want to prevent duplicates selection.